# Does the end user need to install Docker?

Tags: .net, docker, docker-registry

I'm writing a .NET Framework application and decided to use Docker, but every [example online](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) seems to run the `docker run` command from the command line. My end users won't have Docker installed nor will they have experience using the command line. For them, using the app should be:

1. Download app.exe
2. Run it
3. Open app

Not installing Docker and running `docker run`. Am I missing the purpose of Docker here? Isn't supposed to create an exe file that containarize the app in some way?

Comment: How exactly do you expect people to run an application containerized inside a docker image if they don't install docker (or any compatible container runtime as podman, kubernetes, openshift....)?

Comment: @Zeitounator honestly, I have no idea. I thought maybe that would be handled in the exe file? Maybe the exe file would automatically install Docker or something like that? I guess I misunderstood what Docker is really for.

Comment: Why have you decided to use Docker? _"Am I missing the purpose of Docker here?"_ - you have not specified why you have decided to use it, so we need to figure it out first. _"Isn't supposed to create an exe file that containarize the app in some way"_ - no (May be useful - _`.exe` is a common filename extension denoting an executable file (the main execution point of a computer program) for Microsoft Windows, OS/2, and DOS._, AFAIK docker started as Linux containerization tool which then migrated to Windows).

Comment: @boc: this was more a rhetoric question. People will need docker if you decide to deliver a binary packaged in a docker image.

Comment: @Zeitounator I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @GuruStron I was having trouble with ChromeDriver in my C# project, and I heard that we can include missing files in the Dockerfile so the end user installing the app doesn't need to get the ChromeDriver themselves. I know VS has a "Copy file" feature for that, but I thought it would be easier with Docker. But I guess I kinda misunderstood the purpose of docker, because my end users will not know what/how to use Docker.

Comment: @boc it seems that you need to look into installers, not Docker.